# Why does TypeConverter not obey Cultures?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a CSV Reader, so I have a generic casting method. It it, I do this:

```
try
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    if (converter != null)
    {
        result = converter.ConvertFromString(null, culture, value);
        return true;
    }

    result = type.GetDefault();
    return true;
}
catch
{
    result = type.GetDefault();
    return false;
}
```

However if I pass:

type: `int`

value: `"123.024"`

culture: `de-DE`

The converter always fails and returns `0`, instead of correctly treating `.` as a thousands separator.

Anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: Can you share full method?

Comment: TypeConverter is for programmers, it powers the Properties window in Visual Studio.  Using for parsing CSV data, well, not a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [Int32Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.int32converter(v=vs.110).aspx) calls [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) internally, and `Int32.Parse` does not support thousands separators in the string passed to it.

More specifically, `Int32.Parse` format described below:

> The s parameter contains a number of the form:
>
> [ws][sign]digits[ws]
>
> Items in square brackets ([ and ]) are optional. The following table
>   describes each element. Element Description
>
> ws Optional white space.
>
> sign An optional sign
>
> digits A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to
>   9.
>
> The s parameter is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Integer style. In addition to decimal digits, only leading and trailing spaces
>   together with a leading sign are allowed. To explicitly define the
>   style elements that can be present in s, use either the
>   Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles) or the
>   Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider) method.
>
> The s parameter is parsed using the formatting information in a NumberFormatInfo object initialized for the current system culture.
>   For more information, see CurrentInfo. To parse a string using the
>   formatting information of some other culture, use the
>   Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider) method.

If you were calling Int32.Parse directly, you could just call the overload that accepts a NumberStyles enum and create a composite value with the flags you want.  E.g:

```
Int32.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

However, neither `GetConverter()` nor `Int32Converter` have any means of overriding the default `NumberStyles` of `Int32.Parse`, so you will either need a special case for `int`s or you will have to ensure that the strings passed to this function do not contain thousands separators.

Comment: Thanks. So its sounding like I will need to drop `TypeConverter` and instead manually call the parse methods.

Comment: @Tim That is probably for the best.  It is certainly more tedious to have to write code for each specific type, but at least this way it will be easy to add any custom handling that you want or need.